# How to Filter Facebook Plugin to Post a Specific Only Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using [WordPress Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/) to post my new posts from WordPress to my Facebook Page. So far everything works perfectly and I set up an app on my Facebook to integrate with my WordPress.
Now my question is, is there any way to filter the plugin to ONLY post just one specific Custom Post Type, lest's call it "News", to Facebook and not the other post from WordPress native Post or even any other

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can do this way as

get_post_type method
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

to fetch all the corresponding post type and you can also make the condition as 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive

If you read out both you get some idea to implement.

Thanks,
vicky